# why i am getting same row displayed every time using recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Why I am getting same row displayed every time using `RecyclerView`??

I have created an `ArrayList`, called *studentList*, where all data retrieved from database is stored but at time of populating the `RecyclerView`, only the first row of database get populated multiple times.

//database copied from db file//
1   deveah  79  98  99  96  293 97  A+
2   tejas   78  73  75  78  226 75  A
3   sidhesh 96  56  59  58  173 57  B
4   rishabh 58  78  49  38  165 55  B
5   devesh  45  79  96  82  257 85  A
6   Akshay  5   99  76  94  269 89  A

[image]

databaseHelper Class

```
package com.devesh.sqlitedatabase.db;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.devesh.sqlitedatabase.db.model.Student;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StudentDatabasaeHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String STUDENT_DATABASE = "student.db";
    private static final String STUDENT_TABLE = "studentsInfo";

    public StudentDatabasaeHelper( Context context) {
        super(context,STUDENT_DATABASE,null,1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + STUDENT_TABLE + " (ID Integer Primary Key AutoIncrement,STUDENT_NAME text,STUDENT_ROLLNO text,CHEMISTRY Integer,PHYSICS Integer,MATH Integer,TOTAL_MARKS Integer,PERCENTAGE Integer,GRADE text)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + STUDENT_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean InsertStudentData(String roll_no,String name,int chemistry,int physics, int math,int total_marks,int percentage, String grade){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("STUDENT_NAME",name);
        contentValues.put("STUDENT_ROLLNO",roll_no);
        contentValues.put("CHEMISTRY",chemistry);
        contentValues.put("PHYSICS",physics);
        contentValues.put("MATH",math);
        contentValues.put("TOTAL_MARKS",total_marks);
        contentValues.put("PERCENTAGE",percentage);
        contentValues.put("GRADE",grade);

        long result = db.insert(STUDENT_TABLE,null,contentValues);
        if(result == -1) return false;
        else return true;
    }

    public ArrayList<Student> GetStudentData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query  = "select * from " + STUDENT_TABLE;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

        Student model = new Student();
        ArrayList<Student> allStudents = new ArrayList<Student>();

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){

            model.NAME = cursor.getString(1);
            model.ROLL_NO = cursor.getString(2);
            model.CHEMISTRY = cursor.getInt(3);
            model.PHYSICS = cursor.getInt(4);
            model.MATH = cursor.getInt(5);
            model.TOTAL_MARKS = cursor.getInt(6);
            model.PERCENTAGE = cursor.getInt(7);
            model.GRADE = cursor.getString(8);
            allStudents.add(model);
        }
        return allStudents;
    }

}
```

Student Model class

```
package com.devesh.sqlitedatabase.db.model;

public class Student {
    public int ID;
    public String NAME;
    public String ROLL_NO;
    public int CHEMISTRY;
    public int MATH;
    public int PHYSICS;
    public int TOTAL_MARKS;
    public int PERCENTAGE;
    public String GRADE;

//     public Student(int id, String name, String roll_no, int total_marks, int percentage, String grde){
//        this.ID = id;
//        this.NAME = name;
//        this.ROLL_NO = roll_no;
//        this.TOTAL_MARKS = total_marks;
//        this.PERCENTAGE = percentage;
//        this.GRADE = grde;
//    }
//

}
```

ViewActivity class

```
package com.devesh.sqlitedatabase;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.devesh.sqlitedatabase.db.StudentDatabasaeHelper;
import com.devesh.sqlitedatabase.db.model.Student;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    ArrayList<Student> studentList;
//    ArrayList<Student> viewList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
        initData();
        initRecyclerView();
    }

    private void initData() {
        StudentDatabasaeHelper db = new StudentDatabasaeHelper(this);

        studentList = db.GetStudentData();

//        String name = "",roll_no= "",total_marks= "",percent= "",grade= "";
//        int id=0,total=0,percentage=0;
//        Student obj = new Student();
//        int i=0;
//        while (i != studentList.size()) {
//            obj.ID = studentList.get(i).ID;
//            obj.NAME = studentList.get(i).NAME;
//            obj.ROLL_NO =studentList.get(i).ROLL_NO;
//            obj.TOTAL_MARKS = studentList.get(i).TOTAL_MARKS;
//            // String total_marks = String.valueOf(total);
//            obj.PERCENTAGE = studentList.get(i).PERCENTAGE;
//            //String percent = String.valueOf(percentage);
//            obj.GRADE = studentList.get(i).GRADE;
//            viewList.add(obj);
//            i++;
//        }
        Log.d("rogd", "initData: " + studentList.get(1).NAME );

    }

    private void initRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.Student_list_recyclerView);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(studentList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        if(recyclerAdapter !=null){

            recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

RecyclerAdapter class

```
package com.devesh.sqlitedatabase;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.devesh.sqlitedatabase.db.model.Student;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

     ArrayList<Student> studentList;
    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Student> studentList){
        this.studentList = studentList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Student st = studentList.get(position);
            int id = st.ID;
            String strID = String.valueOf(id);
            String name = st.NAME;
            String roll_no = st.ROLL_NO;
//        int chemistry = studentList.get(position).CHEMISTRY;
//        int math = studentList.get(position).MATH;
//        int physics = studentList.get(position).PHYSICS;
            int total_marks = st.TOTAL_MARKS;
            String strTotal_Marks = String.valueOf(total_marks);
            int percentage = st.PERCENTAGE;
            String strPercentage = percentage + "%";
            String grade = st.GRADE;
            ViewHolder.setData(strID,name,roll_no,strTotal_Marks,strPercentage,grade);

            Log.d("rogd", "onBindViewHolder: " + position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return studentList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private static TextView srno;
        private static TextView roll_no;
        private static TextView name;
        private static TextView total_marks;
        private static TextView percentage;
        private static TextView grade;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            srno = itemView.findViewById(R.id.srNo_tv);
            roll_no = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rollno_tv);
            percentage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.percentage_tv);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_tv);
            total_marks = itemView.findViewById(R.id.totalMarks_tv);
            grade = itemView.findViewById(R.id.grade_tv);
        }

        public static void setData(String ID, String name1, String roll_no1, String total_marks1, String percentage1, String grade1){
            srno.setText(ID);
            name.setText(name1);
            roll_no.setText(roll_no1);
            total_marks.setText(total_marks1);
            percentage.setText(percentage1);
            grade.setText(grade1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that your table has the same student data in all of its records! Are you sure this is not the case?

Comment: You can check your table data From the bottom of you android studio, App Inspection ->Database Inspector -> Table Name, You can also check Live Database By Enabling Live Update CheckBox.

Comment: Your RecyclerAdapter is using the wrong ViewHolder, use the one that you have defined & why does your ViewHolder has a static method to use the data?

Comment: i have checked my data data is absolutely fine there are no duplicate records, whats happening is while retrieving data into studentList i think its overwritting data and thats how its getting only last row displayed

Answer (score 0):

first - Change line from

```
ViewHolder.setData(strID,name,roll_no,strTotal_Marks,strPercentage,grade);
```

to

```
holder.setData(strID,name,roll_no,strTotal_Marks,strPercentage,grade);
```

second -

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
```

to

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
```

third

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
```

to

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
```

Comment: That would still cause an error because the `ViewHolder` type defined for the Adapter is `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` & not the `RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder`. Also the static method needs to be a normal public method.

Comment: @DarShan u r right, but it seems to be the root of the problem. updated the answer

Comment: Thanks sir for help , Problem still persists Now, its fetching only last row from database , i feel like data is getting overwritten while fetching thats why it shows only last row from database and it dispalyed as same size of rows ,could help me this problem

Comment: @Deveshkharade which data contains the list at this line?

        this.studentList = studentList;

Comment: Its data that is passed from ViewActivity,and in View its fetched from database by creating new instance of database

Comment: @Deveshkharade check in the debugger which data is in list

Answer (score 0):

You should omit `static` modifier from the data members of the ViewHolder class as it causes you to update the same set of data members every time the `onBindViewHolder()` is called for each row by Recycler View Adapter.

Comment: I already omitted the static but problem remains the same

Comment: @Deveshkharade remove `static` keywords from the class and setData() method as well.

Answer (score -1):

In your `GetStudentData()` inside `StudentDatabasaeHelper`

```
 public ArrayList<Student> GetStudentData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query  = "select * from " + STUDENT_TABLE;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

    Student model = new Student();
    ArrayList<Student> allStudents = new ArrayList<Student>();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()){

      // Student model should be here 
        Student model = new Student();

     ...// rest of your code 
       
        allStudents.add(model);
    }
    return allStudents;
}
```

Student model object is created only once outside `while loop` it should be inside `while loop`.

```
Student model = new Student();
```

What's happening is **Student Class** object is created and assigned a reference and that same object `(named model in your case)` is added to the list with different student records when the last student record is added it assign's all the other objects the last student record.

**Example**

```
Student model = new Student();

model.ID = 1;
list.add(model)

model.ID = 2;
list.add(model)

model.ID = 3;
list.add(model)

model.ID = 4;
list.add(model)
```

The size of the list will be `4` but when i will try to iterate and print the model.id it will always give me `ID = 4`.